# how to keep the last frame in opencv in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I need to keep the information in the last frame in a video file and then calculate PSNR between the last and whole frames.
the video is running! when I get to the last frame I would miss all the previous frames information. so I can not calculate a formula between the last and the first frame :(

```
float *frames;   //this pointer points to the frames
float *p;
for(int i=0; i<sizeof frames; i++){
   ... ;
}
```

I do not know how to fill the for-loop :(

thanks in advance..

Comment: my problem is not the programming part...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can get the last frame of the video in OpenCV C++:

```
void getLastFrame(cv::VideoCapture& video, cv::Mat& frame)
{
    //Get total number of frames in the video
    //Won't work on live video capture
    const int frames = video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

    //Seek video to last frame
    video.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,frames-1);

    //Capture the last frame
    video>>frame;

    //Rewind video
    video.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,0);
}
```

Call this function before starting the processing of video. So that you have the last frame information before getting to any of the other frames.

Comment: wow...good point...thanks a lot...I have access to the last frame but my problem was what you explained.."Call this function before starting the processing of video. So that you have the last frame information before getting to any of the other frames"
thanks again :)

Comment: why your code does not work with float pointer?

i tried with your code but seems incorrect...i am wondering to know why it does not work..

float *p = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frames),8,1);

Comment: The code you mentioned is invalid. `cvCreateImage` returns `IplImage*` not a `float*`. Also, `frames` is an object of type `cv::Mat`. `cvGetSize` won't work on it. Are you using `C` or `C++` API of OpenCV?

Comment: I have already a pointer which points to the frames

"float *Frames;"

I defined another pointer called P to point to the last frame.