# how t get the get the frame information using opencv and c++

Tags: c++, opencv

is there any function in opencv which can be used to get the last frame in a frame sequence?

I tried to use this

```
dst = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
```

but seems just work for IplImage format. I am working with the Mat and the dst should be float pointer.

Comment: Is a frame sequence not just an array of `cvImage`'s? Or better yet `cv::Mat`?

Comment: yes, they are stored in an array now and a float pointer is pointing to them. Now, I do not know any opencv function to use for getting for example the last frame information.

Comment: You will need to post some code showing what your data structure is. If the data is floats, why did you specify IPL_DEPTH_8U?

Comment: yes, the data type is float and I should use 32bit instead. but I think the problem is that this function is not what I should use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to keep the last frame in opencv in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702397/how-to-keep-the-last-frame-in-opencv-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your frames are stored, you might want something like this:

```
float*  frames;    // pointer to array of floats containing N frames;
float* last_frame = frames + (N - 1) * rows * cols;

cv:Mat dst(rows, cols, CV_32FC1, last_frame);
```